# Can you comment the sheets on Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I try to tag why did I create some sheets in Tableau Desktop.

Is there a way to add descriptions/notes/comments to sheets in Tableau?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option available is "Caption". Tableau puts some auto generated text in it, but you may edit that

[image: Caption]

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved, it will help everyone